# font-awesome icon link to a URL, need ideas and solutions

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

how is this done? my attempt was doing this

```
 <%=link_to "<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x "></i>", https://www.facebook.com/pages/Inyourshoes/1464365723776237 %>
```

clearly i found out its not right because it can only take a body as a arguement aka string. Ive tried googling the question and havent found much resources

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Inyourshoes/1464365723776237" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x "></i>
<% end %>
```

here is the documentation for link_to: [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: bravo sir, thank you! if you dont mind explaining, can you explain the syntax behind the do %>?

Comment: I just edited my answer to provide the link to the documentation. The format without "do" is like a short version of the helper. The link_to accepts a block( link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block) ).